# NODE.JS configure server/index.js to run from server location

Tags: node.js, express

I have a React NODE.JS app which i want to configure to run from a server location on proxy-pass. 
I have found some tutorials about this which suggest adding the location in the app.use.express line:

The location needs to be http://dev.apps.net/npt/

```
app.use("/npt/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));
```

However, nothing loads after this, the request is still going to the initial url.

this is my **sever/index.js** file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require("./config/configProvider")();
const passport = require("passport");
const sequelize = require("sequelize");
const DataTypes = sequelize.DataTypes;
const Types = require("./models/types")(sequelize, DataTypes);
const { find } = require("./middlewares/mysql");
const path = require("path");
const { errorHandler } = require("./middlewares/generics");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());

config.db
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection has been established successfully.");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Unable to connect to the database:", err);
  });

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb", extended: true }));

// uncommment below code for static front end development version to work properly
// app.use("/npt/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));

//initialize passport to have it available on server
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use("/users", require("./controllers/users"));

require("./passport");
app.use(passport.authenticate("jwt", { failureRedirect: "/" }));

app.use("/usersPrivate", require("./controllers/usersPrivate"));
app.use("/schedule", require("./controllers/schedule"));
app.use("/types", find(Types));

app.use(errorHandler);

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app
  .listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on: ${port}`);
  })
  .on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(`Error starting server: ${error}.`);
    restart();
  });

const restart = (code = 1) => {
  console.log(`Restarting services in 10 seconds.`);
  setTimeout(() => {
    process.exit(code);
  }, 10000);
};
```

Do i need to make any other modifications for it to work?

I am using version 4.17.1 of express.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you haven't used this line of code in your `server/index`:

`app.use("/npt/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));`

Comment: the line is commented as it is intended only for the build version. I am using it when deploying on production... :)

Comment: @AlexBran have you checked your build to make sure it is included in the build version?

Comment: if i use the /np/ in this line ```app.use("/npt/", express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "../client/build")));``` nothing works. however, If I add the location in the base url than it loads my sign in page when i load the url/npt:
```
export const baseURL = `${window.location.origin}/npt/`
```